# Using the GSL Libraries to Make Splines and Using them for Integration

Tags: c++, c, interpolation, gsl, numerical-integration

Say I have a set of N data points. I can use the gsl library gsl_splines.h routines to create a spline of this data. What I would like to do is to use this spline and the gsl integration library to find the integral of these data. I'm working in C here.

In my code, I have generated the splines I'd use, and since the splines are smooth, I'm judging by eye, I'd expect this method would be more efficient than evaluating the splines and using an algorithm like the trapezoid rule to find the integral, but I'm having trouble coming up with a way to piece the two things together.

If you can provide any simple examples, I would appreciate it!

If the gsl libraries aren't what you'd use, I'd be glad to hear any other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

> and since the splines are smooth, I'm judging by eye, I'd expect this method would be more efficient than evaluating the splines and using an algorithm like the trapezoid

This is a fallacy. You're *assuming* that your data is approximated better by a spline of some order than by a step function, but you have nothing to support that. The only thing you have is a bunch of `(x, f(x))` pairs. Using midpoint integration is a perfectly respectable way of approximating the integral here. A big plus: You can easily implement it yourself.

Comment: Hi Nico, I answered my own question, which you can see how is compares to the trapezoidal rule, or with some small modifications and of the other rules. I recognized my assumption, which is why I made the comment. The idea was to test this method against some of the summation rules to see which method provided better results. I could have mentioned that, but I didn't think it was necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to make this happen more quickly and with better accuracy that the trapezoidal rule. The key was to use the spline objects as the members of the structure my_f_params, since the GSL integration demands a gsl_function object,

https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/integration.html#c.gsl_integration_qags.

Here's an example code for integrating 1/x from 1 to 1200, which isn't necessarily beautiful code, I'm a physicist not a computer scientist:

```
// Complie with 
// gcc -w -o Spline_Integration_Test Spline_Integration_Test.c -lgsl -lgslcblas -lm

#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_spline.h>
#include <gsl/gsl_integration.h>
#include <time.h>


double funk(double x, void *p);
struct my_f_params { gsl_interp_accel *facc; gsl_spline *fspline; };

double funk(double x, void *p)
{
    struct my_f_params * params = (struct my_f_params *)p;
    gsl_interp_accel *facc = (params->facc);
    gsl_spline *fspline = (params->fspline);

    double f = gsl_spline_eval (fspline, x, facc);
    return f;
}

int main()
{
    int i, N = 10000000;
    double *x; x = (double *)malloc((size_t)sizeof(double) * N); memset(x,0,(size_t) sizeof(double)*N);
    double *f; f = (double *)malloc((size_t)sizeof(double) * N); memset(f,0,(size_t) sizeof(double)*N);
    gsl_interp_accel *facc = gsl_interp_accel_alloc();
    gsl_spline *fspline = gsl_spline_alloc (gsl_interp_cspline, N);

    x[0] = 0.0;
    f[0] = x[0]*x[0];
    for(i=1; i<N; i++)
    {
        x[i] = x[i-1] + 0.001;
        f[i] = 1/x[i];
    }

    gsl_spline_init(fspline, x, f, N);

    clock_t begin = clock();
    gsl_integration_workspace * w = gsl_integration_workspace_alloc (1000);

    struct my_f_params params = { facc, fspline };

    double result, error;

    gsl_function F;
    F.function = &funk;
    F.params = &params;

    // Beginning GSL/spline integration part
    gsl_integration_qags (&F, 1, 1200, 0, 1e-7, 1000, w, &result, &error);

    clock_t end = clock();
    double time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Time for Spline Integration:         = %9f s \n", time_spent);


    // Begining trapezoidal integration part
    begin = clock();
    double a, b = 0.0;
    double delta;
    for(i=1000; i<1200*1000; i++)
    {
        delta = 0.001;
        if(i==1||i==N) a = 1.0/x[i];
        else a = 2.0/x[i];
        b += a*(delta)/2.0;
    }
    end = clock();
    time_spent = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("Time for Trapezoidal Integration:    = %9f s \n\n", time_spent);

    printf ("Result for Spline Integration     =  %.18f\n", result);
    printf ("Estimated error                   =  %.18f\n", error);
    printf ("Intervals                         =  %zu\n\n", w->size);

    printf("Result for Trapezoidal Integration = %f \n", b);

    gsl_integration_workspace_free (w);
    free(x); free(f);

    return 0;
}
```